# Getting Typescript error when trying to clear form using clear() in vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am getting a typescript error when trying to reset a form when the user clicks on reset button.

```
onClearSearchFormClicked() {
  this.$refs.searchForm.reset();
}
```

```
197:27 Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'Element | Element[] | Vue | Vue[]'.
  Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'Element'.
    196 |   onClearSearchFormClicked() {
  > 197 |     this.$refs.searchForm.reset();
        |                           ^
    198 |   }
Version: typescript 3.8.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't advise the other answers. TypeScript is correctly telling you that the object could not be a HtmlFormElement. Instead of forcing the casting and suppressing the error, you'd rather use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
if (this.$refs.searchForm instanceof HTMLFormElement) {
  this.$refs.searchForm.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked.

```
  onClearSearchFormClicked() {
    //this.$refs.searchForm.reset();
    (this.$refs.searchForm as HTMLFormElement).reset();
  }
```

Comment: No worries, I saw you're new, which is why I told you you shouldn't have done it. In general, if someone answers your question and helps you solve your issue, you should upvote it and, eventually mark it as appropriate (accepted) answer. That will help future users with a similar problem spot the right answer faster. On the bright side, Cristian added a better answer than mine, which is why I deleted mine and upvoted his. If I were you, I'd mark it as accepted, as it is correct. Welcome to [SO]. Stay safe & happy coding!